# Rails: changing from three columns in a table to one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am modifying a `Documents` table from using three columns (`article1`, `article2`, and `article3`) to one (`articles`) which has a string of comma-separated IDs stored in it (i.e., `23,4,33,2`). That's all working well, but I'm trying to adjust the functions that read the three columns to read the one and I'm getting rather stuck.

In the model I have:

```
scope :all_articles, lambda {|p| where(:page => p) }
```

In the controller I have this:

```
@articles = (1..3).to_a.map { |i| Article.all_articles(i).reverse }
```

And in the view:

```
<% @articles.each_with_index do |a, i| %>
  <%= a[i].name %>
<% end %>
```

It's just a bit beyond me at this point.

Cheers!

Comment: Is there any reason that you are storing multiple IDs in a column instead of using foreign keys?

Comment: Mostly because I've no idea what a foreign key is.

Comment: Does an article belong to only one document?  Or can an article belong to many different documents?

Comment: So basically, an article has many documents and a document can have many articles?

Comment: That's exactly it, yeah. I should have explained that earlier.

Comment: Can you explain what this is supposed to do?  `(1..3).to_a.map { |i| Article.all_articles(i).reverse }`

Comment: It builds an array of instance variable names so I can loop through the view code for each article. I think.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20901/discussion-between-sean-hill-and-mileorsohigh)

Comment: `(1..3).to_a` is `[1,2,3]`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually not good practice to put store the ids in a column like you have done.  It is better to break that relationship out into a Has and Belongs to Many relationship.  You set it up in your models like this:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
  #...
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  #... 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :documents
end
```

Then you will create a join table that ActiveRecord will use to store the relationships.

```
create_table :articles_documents, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :article_id
  t.integer :document_id
end

add_index :articles_documents, [:article_id, :document_id], unique: true
```

This will allow you to query a lot more efficiently than you are currently doing.  For example, to find all documents that have some article id.  You would do:

```
@documents = Document.joins(:articles).where("articles.id = ?", some_article_id)
```

Or if you want to query for a document and return the articles with it:

```
@documents = Document.includes(:articles).where(some_conditions)
```

Comment: What does the `add_index...` line do here? The migration fails for me, and I suspect it's because of that.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  See my edit.  I had copied that from another answer and forgot to update that part.

Comment: Anyway, it creates a unique index that prevents you from creating the same pair twice.  It also allows the db to search more efficiently.

Comment: I've taken your advice and begun to convert the relations to your methodology, but I've hit a wall. I've got this (`@document = Document.includes(:articles).find(params[:id])`) in the controller which works fine for the the Document-level stuff, but it doesn't access the relevant articles. I've got `<% @document.articles.each_with_index do |a, i| %><%= a[i].name %><% end %>` in the view and I'm rather stuck. I don't know if I have to change anything in the Document controller to have it work, either. Ha.

Comment: Okay, so you just need to change that part to `@documents.articles.each do |a|` and then `a.name`.

Comment: `a`, in this case, is going to represent an individual article, not an array, which is why you are seeing that error.

Comment: I've done that, but the articles refuse to show up even though the document works. It feels like I have to change the form for saving the articles into the documents, but I'm not sure how to do that. They were initially saving Article IDs into separate fields in the Document form, if you cast your mind back. My `f.collection_select` points to `article1`, `article2`, and `article3`. Again, thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: I've got it to work with a nested form of sorts.      `<% Article.all.each do |a| %><%= check_box_tag("dociment[article_ids][]", a.id, @document.articles.include?(a.id)) %><%= a.name %><% end %>`. Thanks so much!